# How to put the values of a column of an internal table into a variant?

Tags: abap, sap-basis

Can somebody help me figure out if there is a way for the query below:

I have an internal table with one column with 69 records.

I want all these 69 records to be populated into a variant and get saved so that with this variant and the values saved in it I can run a particular program

How can I populate these values ?

Comment: You don't need to ABAP for that, just create the variant via GUI and put values there.

Comment: @sumegha mukherjee: Why do you want specifically the variant method? This data you are talking about is the values of a specific select-option? Why not setting dynamically at the start of the program?

Comment: Just save your itab to file or to clipboard from debugger and do like knut said then.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is a bit unclear for me.

- Do you speak about two programs or one program?
- What's the parameter you want to fill in the variant?

I'll just give you some hints - depending on your situation you must pick the correct parts.

> I have an internal table with one column with 69 records.

How is the internal table filled?

> I want all these 69 records to be populated into a variant and get saved so that with this variant and the values saved in it I can run a particular program

- You have a program and you want to save a selection in a variant. So you need some parameters for the selection screen.
- You want a table, so you need a `SELECT-OPTION`.
- To define a `SELECT-OPTION` you need a DDIC-reference (you must say, what kind of field you want.). In the following example I use a material number (`MARA-MATNR`).

So you program contains something like:

```
TABLES mara.
SELECT-OPTIONS: s_matnr FOR mara-matnr.
```

With this you would get:
[image]

You can define ranges (from-to) and list of values. As you want only single values, you need something like:

```
SELECT-OPTIONS: s_matnr FOR mara-matnr NO INTERVALS.
```

Now you get:

[image]

- When you push (1) you can enter values.
- With (2) you can load from an external file,
- with (3) you can load values from clipboard.

So you can fill your values and store the selection in a variant.

When you execute your program, the data is stored in a ranges table:
[image]

Now you can loop on this table and copy the `S_MATNR-LOW` value into your internal table for further processing.

---

If I misunderstood you question and you want to create a variant dynamically, then take a look on function module `RS_VARIANT_ADD` (or `RS_VARIANT_COPY`,`RS_VARIANT_CHANGE`...)

Answer (score 0):

You could always put the values in TVARVC, either manually or via code.  Then specify the TVARVC variable in the variant definition.